# DirectX redistributable Installed, but not present in Windows folder

Tags: windows, directx

I have installed the directx redistributable june 2010 in my machine(Win Xp servicepack 3)
But it is not present in Windows>Microsoft.NET folder.Vs 2010 is installed in the machine.Is that a problem......Let me know, if there is a solution.....thanks.

Comment: What part of DirectX would you expect to be installed in the .NET directory?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: DirectX for Managed Code>Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.dll